# SQL: Split post code value to return 'outer' part of code

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got a results set of UK postcodes. Some are formatted with spaces, and some are not e.g. S14HG and S1 4HG

I want my select query to just return the outer part of the post code value in the results, i.e. 'S1'

I can do this in Excel using the following formula:

`=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)),””,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))`

Is it possible to perform the same function in SQL through a SELECT query?

Comment: Does your list of postcodes not contain ones with more than 2 letters/numbers in the out code?  Such as BT23?

Comment: Hi @iamdave - yes it does, there's about 30k records so there's a good sample of UK postcode variations. The above formula works across all the values I've run it against, irrespective of the number of characters.

Comment: My solution is simply a SQL version of your Excel formula.  Are you confident your postcodes are all correct or do you also need to be doing validation?

Comment: Thanks @iamdave , yes, the quality of the data is ok - it's just the spacing that's an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UK postcode can have one of [many formats for their outward code.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation)

However, as you can see from the possible formats in that link, there is a consistent format for the remainder of the postcode.  If you are confident your postcodes are correct, you can simply remove any spaces and the last 3 characters:

```
declare @Postcodes table (Postcode nvarchar(10));
insert into @Postcodes values
 ('S1 4HG')
,('S14HG')
,('S10 4HG')
,('S104HG');

select Postcode
        ,replace(left(Postcode,len(Postcode)-3),' ','') as OutwardCode
from @Postcodes
```

Output:

```
Postcode    OutwardCode
S1 4HG      S1
S14HG       S1
S10 4HG     S10
S104HG      S10
```

Comment: Plus1 for the supporting link  -  some interesting info there

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  They are a nightmare to validate.  With every new road built in the UK a new one is added to the list of valid codes.  You can check the `A99 A99 | AA9 A99 | etc` format and get false positives or you can check against a list of millions in the official [Postcode Address File](http://www.royalmail.com/business/services/marketing/data-optimisation/paf), but this costs money to receive the updates and they are anything up to 6 months out of date due to the release schedule.

Comment: Insanity!  Makes me appreciate the US Zip Codes

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  It really hits home just what a pain it is when you try to buy something like home insurance and both the website and the person on the end of the phone tells you your address doesn't exist because your residence is 'too new'.

Comment: Cheers @iamdave - I've got that working great thanks.

Comment: Hmm, @iamdave On closer inspection it would appear I must have some data validation issues, as the query runs fine across half of the dataset and then errors: "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Is it possible to build in some sort of error-handling for blanks, nulls, etc?

Comment: @Jon295087 you have a post code that is only 2 or fewer characters. You can use a case or something similar to check `,case when len(Postcode) < 3 then null else replace(left(Postcode,len(Postcode)-3),' ','') end  as OutwardCode`

Comment: @Jon295087  The `case` that scsimon posted is what you need in the immediate, though it would appear that you also need to start validating your postcodes...

Comment: @scsimon - apologies for the delayed reply, but just got around to testing this and it works great. Appreciate the info. You were correct, one of the postcode records contained a #, and this was throwing the error. Cheers.

Comment: @iamdave - I wouldn't disagree with you. Unfortunately the system I'm pulling the data from is fed from multiple sources, and postcode validation isn't used on some of the entry routes. There's definitely a piece of work to improve the quality, but it's out of scope for the piece I'm currently working on I'm afraid.

Comment: Cheers mate @Jon295087

Answer (score -2):

You can use `LEFT()` regardless of spaces since you only want the first two, which won't have a space.

```
SELECT LEFT('S1 4HG',2)
```

Or just get rid of the spaces...

```
declare @t varchar(64) = 'S   1     4     H     G'

SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(@t,' ',''),2)
```

Comment: This only works for postcodes with a single letter and number out code.  There are a number of valid variations on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Outward_code

Comment: @iamdave can you elaborate? They wanted the first two characters based off the sample data. If there is some other rules the OP needed taken into consideration they need to state that. If there aren't spaces in "some" then how would one determine what's "outer" and what's "inner"? If we are to research wiki and take into consideration all the rules in the 11 bullet points then the question needs to be closed... this would be a UK postal code parser function... in which no effort has been given

Comment: They requested retrieving the "outer part of the postcode".  In the case of the `S1` example given this officially called the "Outward Code".  Per the link I provided, there is consistent enough of a format to indeed split out the Outward code as the remainder of the postcode is always 3 characters, excluding the space.

Comment: Hi @scsimon - the above comment is correct on this point, I need the solution to be able to handle all variations of UK postcode

Comment: @iamdave and SO community is expected to know this? Kudos to you for working for free and doing research on-behalf of the OP. I try and enable and teach versus just provide answers.

Comment: @Jon295087 Read The [Help Page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with emphasis on [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to provide complete questions.

Comment: I did no research for this question in particular, this is just something I have had to do myself in the past.  If you are not knowledgeable on the subject matter of a question perhaps you shouldn't be jumping to answer.  Even if you don't know about UK postcodes, my solution is an exact SQL replica of the Excel formula provided in the question (and stated as being the logic that needed replicating) whereas yours does not.

Comment: Just having scrolled back up, the question is actually very literally "How do I perform the same function in SQL?"

Comment: Will do. Apologies @scsimon, I'd made a presumption people would be familiar with UK postcode variants (though in my defence I did state this in the original question) - I appreciate that these are different to the format used in the States.

Comment: @iamdave My point was anyone NOT from the UK wouldn't likely know this. It wasn't a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. And your translation of one language to the next goes against #1 and #3 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Jon295087 it's not a big deal. You clarified later which is what is important and understand now about MCVE. No sweat brother.